# Spaces inside a list

Tags: python, list

I'm currently stuck with this problem.
I will first explain what i want the program to do.

I have this code:

```
rij4 = []
rij3 = []
rij2 = []
rij1 = list (range(1,16))
print("{}".format(rij1))

for x in range(0,14):
    cijfer = int((rij1[x] * rij1[x+1]) // (rij1[x+1] - rij1[x]))
    rij2.append(cijfer)
print(rij2)

for x in range(0,13):
    cijfer = int((rij2[x] * rij2[x+1]) // (rij2[x+1] - rij2[x]))
    rij3.append(cijfer)
print(rij3)
```

This will result in the list being printed but the number need to stand above eachoter. Also the [ ] need to be gone in the print.

So for example, i would like this printed:

```
1  2  3  4   5   6   7   8   9  10   11    12    13   14  15
2  6 12 20  30  42  56  72  90 110  132   156   182  210
3 12 30 60 105 168 252 360 495 660  858  1092  1365
```

Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: do `print(" ".join([str(x) for x in rij3])))` instead

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can play a bit with format to achieve what you want. You can have an integer `x` padded with `' '` character using the following code:

```
"{: 3d}".format(x)
```

This pads `x` to 3 digits by prepending spaces. Also to print a list `l` separated by a single space you can do `" ".join(l)`. Now if you combine the two you get:

```
print(" ".join(["{: 3d}".format(x) for x in rij3]))
```

This is more or less what you want(possibly you need to add line breaks where you want them).

Comment: Good answer, +1. Could you expand a bit on the format pattern, perhaps do the whole thing in 2 lines, so that future visitors have an easier time understanding?

Comment: @slezica I expanded my answer to make it more detailed.